# Flutter Firestore - Nested collection is always empty

Tags: flutter, loops, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(currentUser!.uid)
        .collection("workouts")
        .doc(workoutId)
        .collection("exercises")
        .get()
        .then((exercises) {
      if (exercises.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for (int i = 0; i < exercises.docs.length; i++) {
          setsList.add(exercises.docs[i].data() as ExerciseSet);
        }
        setState(() {
          for (ExerciseSet set in setsList) {
            print(set.weight);

            completedExerciseSetRows.add(DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(Text(setCount.toString())),
              //const DataCell(VerticalDivider(thickness: 5)),
              DataCell(Text(set.weight.toString())),
              //const DataCell(VerticalDivider(thickness: 5)),
              DataCell(Text(set.reps.toString())),
              //const DataCell(VerticalDivider(thickness: 5)),
              DataCell(
                  (isSetToFailure == true) ? Icon(Icons.check) : Icon(null))
              //const DataCell(VerticalDivider(thickness: 5)),
            ]));
          }
        });
      }
    });
```

I want to loop through the "exercises" collection, but the "exercises" collection is always empty (it shows List items = 0).

Also, do I need to hit the database again if I want to iterate through the collection in each "exercise".

Comment: I think this throws an error here `setsList.add(exercises.docs[i].data() as ExerciseSet);` since `data()` returns `Map<String, dynamic>` that cannot simply be cast to `ExerciseSet`.

Comment: I have a try - onException, it doesn't go there. Also, the part of the code that you are mentioning doesn't get executed. And the question really is why is the "exercises" collection empty.

Comment: can you refer to this link : https://mullr.dev/2020/07/05/handling-nested-objects-in-firestore-with-flutter/ is it helpful?